# refs does not work in react in order to call child method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refs

There are two component in react project.
1, Parent
2, Child

Now, I'd like to use childMethod in Parent component.
In some pages of stackoverflow, everyone said refs is effective.
But in my project, it's not working.

```
class Parent extends Component {
 parentMethod(){
   this.refs.child.childMethod();
 }

 render() {
  return (
    <Child ref='child'/>
  );
 }
}



class Child extends Component {
 childMethod() {
    alert('You made it!');
 }
 render() {
  return (
    <h1 ref="hello">Hello</h1>
  );
 }
}
```

When I use above code, there is one error code in browser console.
**_this3.refs.child.childMethod is not a function**

I'd like to use child method, so I have 2 questions.
1, What's "_this3" ? How can I use refs correctly?
2, Do you have any other idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Parent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // binding methods to the class so they don't lose 'this'
    // when invoked from another environment.
    this.parentMethod = this.parentMethod.bind(this);
    this.setChildRef = this.setChildRef.bind(this);
  }

  parentMethod() {
    this.childNode.childMethod();
  }

  // intentionally avoided using an arrow fuction inside JSX
  // for we don't want a new anonymous fn created on every render.
  setChildRef(node) { // receives reference to component as argument
    this.childNode = node;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child ref={this.setChildRef}/>
        <button onClick={this.parentMethod}>Parent Button - Click me :)</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  childMethod() {
    alert('You made it!');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Child</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/free_soul/9vrLrw8h/

---

1. What's "_this3"?

   > *Probably a variable that you may see in browser while debugging. It just represents an execution context.*
2. How can I use refs correctly?

   > *It is preferred to treat the `ref` as a [callback attribute](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-callback-attribute) and no longer depend on the refs Object. If you do use the refs Object, avoid
   >   accessing refs of descendant components. You should treat `refs` as a
   >   private accessor and not part of a component's API. Treat only the
   >   methods exposed on a component instance as its public API.*

Comment: I tried to use it. 
But it's not working.

this.childNode.childMethod is not a function(…)

Comment: That shouldn't happen. I have posted a working demo here https://jsfiddle.net/free_soul/9vrLrw8h/

Comment: Let me know what you're seeing.